# How to set a variable to the indexPath.section of the cell selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When a user taps on a cell in my `UITableView`, I want to set the `sectionSelected` variable to the `indexPath.section` of that cells respective section, and then send that variable over to the next view controller in a segue.

Here's how I'm currently attempting this:

**MatchCenterViewController.h:**

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger *sectionSelected;
```

**MatchCenterViewController.m:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Set _sectionSelected variable to the section index
    self.sectionSelected = indexPath.section;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MCExpandedSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MCExpandedSegue"]){
        MCExpandedViewController *controller = (MCExpandedViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.sectionSelected = self.sectionSelected;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, and it appears that the reason for this is because of the following warning I get on the line setting `self.sectionSelected`:
`Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')`

How can I correctly setup the variable?

Comment: NSInteger is a value type, you don't need the `*`, `@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger sectionSelected;`

Comment: The duplicate is pretty close to this question, and the answer mentions `NSInteger`s, too.

Comment: I'm unsure of what the type of sectionSelected is on your controller but there is a simpler way to do this. If you're tableView has selection enabled, you could use the tableView property for 
indexPathForSelectedRow. NSIndex path contains Int values and not NSInteger values. It would even be better for you to store NSNumber values if you truly want the section. Also, any variable that is assign is typically not a pointer and is a primitive value. Change your property from a pointer to a non pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger *sectionSelected;
```

To

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger sectionSelected;
```